# How wamp server works,from converting the program to output

Tags: php, apache, wamp

In Wamp, what is the role of Apache server,SSL,php parser & SQL database from converting the program(php)  to output.What is the function of each software (i.e.,Apache server,SSL,php parser & SQL database)that is used in wamp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acronym WAMP refers (Microsoft Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP). It is the alternative stack for the popular LAMP where L refers to Linux.

When we talk about a development stack we're referring to the set of software applications that work together to provide web services.

Apache is used to listen for incoming web requests from browsers on specific ports. The standard port for web requests is 80, and 443 for SSL. Each request made by a browser is interpreted by the Apache services to yield a response. The most common type of response is a HTML document which the browser displays.

When Apache is used with PHP the web requests are forwarded to the PHP interpreter. Which executes the PHP scripts as software instructions that generate the HTML document. PHP as a programming language can be very complex and people often use frameworks like CakePHP, Laravel or the Zend Framework. These are tools that help them make web applications.

MySQL is a database engine that allows applications written in PHP to read, write and delete data on the fly using SQL queries.

We call all the above the WAMP or LAMP stack because of it's popularity. It itself is not a standard but just an acronym that refers to when these tools are all working together. Over the years the popularity of this stack has resulted in people publishing easy to install packages that contain all the above, but in general you simply running this stack if you install them on the same network (or computer) and connect them together.

Comment: I think you meant "interpreted", not "interrupted".

Comment: @ryantxr thanks, although it sometimes feels like PHP interrupts the requests.

Comment: How is it that WAMP does not have an explanation like this?

Comment: @ryantxr because WAMP/LAMP don't have a governing group of people who maintain "what it is". Where as; MEAN (http://mean.io/) which is also a stack has it's own website and people who maintain it. I think WAMP/LAMP is just very old and everyone just assumes you know what it means.

Comment: @cgTag tq for the answer